# Mobile applications and user data security

Tags: authentication, identity-management

My question is in regards to user data stored within mobile applications, after dealing with security issues of hacked firmware and manipulated apps. Is there a system that prevents modification to the manifest file and privileges of an application? Something like this would also be beneficial to the developer's work.

Answer (score 2):

No, there's no such mechanism.

If your software runs on a client hardware, the client can subvert any protection on the software side. It may take a while, may take a lot of effort, but no software protection can withstand forever against an attacker with full access to the hardware.

For example, look at the protections Sony put on their PlayStation 4 gaming platform. It had several layers of protections: firmware encryption, memory encryption, hypervisor, digital signatures and digital keys, and even with all those protections it was possible to run custom code on it.

And it would make little sense to change the manifest and add capabilities that the application would never use. Adding a capability means nothing unless the application code is changed too. And if the attacker is repackaging the application, it can trivially change the manifest and sign the application with his own key.

The Application Store (Google Play or Apple App Store) would not accept this changed application there, but it's possible to sideload applications from outside the app store. Usually users do this for acquiring paid applications for free, and those users would be in risk of installing malicious copies of the application.

Comment: Thank you, I have a lot of information that I believe could be helpful however I do not trust any outlet. I was hacked and I am still going through this. I don't own a computer or laptop. I'm limited to the abilities of a smart phone. I have lost many email accounts and I've been through several phones. Going by my research, I have seen multiple hacking methods. My firmware is hacked and apps modified including the icons. I don't know what to do anymore. I cannot back up any data as it's all stolen or modified. It is as if the whole last year my life is being erased they appear to be me.

Comment: The most common method for hacking a smartphone is by installing applications outside of the App Store. If your phone is hacked, a firmware reinstall can solve the problem.

Comment: Thank you. I have attempted to search for firmware. I'm being redirected or I receive a 404 with any promising search.